# Why does Flask look in two different directories for templates?

Tags: python, templates, flask

I'm working on my first Flask-based Python web app. It is working fine locally, but when I upload it, I have a problem with file paths.

The Flask app is currently looking for two different pages, at these addresses:

mysite.org/flaskapp/
mysite.org/flaskapp/about/

The links to the first (home) page work fine. But the link to the About page jumps up a directory, to mysite.org/about/ .

I've looked at lots of stackoverflow questions and other resources, and I've tried using the template_folder argument, but I haven't been able to convince the app to look in the right place for both files.

Here is the mapping from the root file in the application:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the relevant part of the html template:

```
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href=".">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="./about">About</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: You should remove the `.`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using standard Jinja2 templating, which means instead of hardcoding URL paths in your templates you should be using [url_for()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for).

`url_for()` takes the endpoint's func name as an argument and returns the local path for the URL, which means it does all the hard work for you. When adding `url_for()` to your template, it would look like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That change fixes half of the problem--thank you. It does create a link that appears to point to the correct address: mysite.org/flaskapp/about/. And that's perfect. But on the server, when I click that link, it STILL jumps up a directory and serves that page mysite.org/about/ . The same thing happens if I directly enter the url mysite.org/flaskapp/about/ -- the site just drops the middle of the address and takes me to mysite.org/about/.

Comment: Can't diagnose without server config, but sounds like a server issue initially. What is the request and response headers from the server on pages that don't behave as expected? Are they being 301'd or 302'd by nginx etc. or Flask? Did you set your Flask `SERVER_NAME='mysite.org/flaskapp'` the same value as your virtual host in your server config? I would guess mismatch between flask's server_name and your virtual host name.